How to use microsoft azure translator for translate web pages
microsoft azure website is also using this 
like google translator 
i am not want to use text translator , i wan to transalate my whole websites in selected language.
Microsoft od=ffers three types of translation

Text Tranlation
Documents Translation
Custom Trannslation

which of these is being used to translate .net mvc websites

edge browser has a built in plugin to translate websites. Would that work for you?
